# Why is different stdout with zmore and jar files?

Tags: java, linux, command-line, ant, jar

I have the next problem with stdout. For example I type the command:

```
$ zmore lib.jar
------> lib.jar <------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: Lib Demo
```

However when I write the same command using libraries that have generated myself not appear the "Specification-Title":

```
$ zmore lib2.jar
------> lib2.jar <------
```

lib2.jar is generated with ant build using `<jar>` tag:

```
<jar jarfile="Builder/target/lib2.jar" basedir="Builder/target/classes">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="Lib2"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Why appear "Specification-Title" whith lib.jar and not with lib2.jar?
 
Thanks for advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Are you sure zmore can handle .jar (i.e. .zip) files?

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details of the best way to quote code - see the source version of my edit as an example.

Comment: Thanks Jon. @Henry yes It's possible and very useful to get version from .jar quickly